# Can we access Custom Console component using Salesforce API

Tags: custom-console-components

We already have a page layout for Contacts object and a custom console component on the contacts page layout.

We are planning to replace the standard page layout for contacts with a VF page and at the same time, we want to retain the custom console component.

Is there any way to access the custom console component using Salesforce API ( in order to access the custom console component within the VF page)

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could use either the metadata API to read info about Layout objects, or the describeLayout method from the SOAP API to get details about a specific page layout associated with a certain record type and ID. After you have the detail of which VF page was acting as the console component you could render that into your main VF page as a sidebar.

You may also be pleasantly surprised at what the console does out of the box. In my test org I just over-ride the View action with a VF page that uses Case as the StandardController, and the sidebars I configured in the page layout show up automagically.